# How much punya does Kanya Dana give?

Tags: marriage, punyam, daana

How how much punya does the father get from a kanya dana?

What is the phala for a kanya dana?

Comment: Can punya be measured? If so how?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma How much? quantizable?  Is it like when you earn one unit of BhuDaanPunya (BDP) by donating an acre of arable land and a centi_BDP for a cent  given away?

Comment: @Narasimham Ask the OP. That is what he asked in the body. I only edited to reflect it in the title also.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Based on the fruit it gives, and/or comparison with other Yajnas, like the Ashwamedha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard that it gives the father the Brahma Loka. But, the references I have collected only say that it guaranties the father a place in the celestial region. Also, it bestows merit equal to performing a Jyotistoma Vedic Yajna.

Following verses are from the Samvarta Smriti:

> He, who, decorating a maiden with ornaments, gives her, unto a
>   becoming bridegroom, according to the Brahma mode of marriage', enjoys
>   extraordinary prosperity by the virtue of the giving away of the
>   maiden, acquires the applause of the pious, and attains to un-ending
>   fame. (61,62)
>
> Having given away [a maiden], sanctified with Homa Mantrams, **a person
>   attains the fruits of hundreds of Jyotistoma-Sacrifice.** (63)
>
> Having given away a maiden-daughter, decorated with ornaments, clothes
>   and seats **a father attains to the celestial region and is adored of
>   the Suras (celestials)** . (64)

EDIT:

Regarding the Brahmaloka Prapti, I have found a mantra recited during the ritual. [This website](http://vedvikas.blogspot.com/2013/01/kanya-dana-mantram.html) has the mantra and it says the mantra is from Smritiratna (which is a Smriti digest).

> According to Smrtiratnam, the following mantra is to be recited at
>   the time of performing kanyA dAnam during vivAha :
>
> kanyAm lakshaNa samyuktAm kanakAbharaNairyutAm|
>  dAsyami vishNave
>   tubhyam **brahmaloka jigIshayA** ||
>
> **Desiring to reach the abode of Brahma**, I give as kanyA DAnam  the bride with good features and decked with golden ornaments to you (a
>   deserving groom) who is VishNu svarUpa

EDIT1:

The procedure of Kanya Dana is mentioned in great details in the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php). The Sankalpa mantra clearly states the purpose of the Dana or the fruit to be achieved in return.

> **Kanyaa Daana Prakriya:**
>
> The Jyotirvetta would rearr ange the seating arrangement as a
>   preliminary to t he key act of Kanyaadaana; the groom would face ea st
>   and the bride would face west while the Kanya d aata and his wife
>   would be seated on the southern side and having taken ‘Kushaas ‘in
>   hand accomplis h the act of Kanya daana as follows :
>
> [Mamopaatta duritakshaya dwaraa Parameshwara preetyartham shubhey
>   shobhaney muhurtey Shri Vishnoraagnayaa Adya Brahmanah Dwiteeya
>   ParaardheyVaivaswata Manvantare y Kali yugey pradhamey paadey Jambu
>   dwipey Bharata VarsheyBharata Khandey Meror dakshina digbhaagey
>   Aryaavartey or Shri Shailasya Ishanya orVayavya o r Agneya pradeshey
>   etc. Samastha Devataa Brahmana Guru jana sannidhou Asmin Vartamaana
>   Vyavahaarika Chaandra maanena or Surya maanena --- Samvatsarey,
>   --Ayanye—Rutou,--- Maasou,--Pakshou—Shubha Tithou —Shubha Vaasarey—Shubha Nakshatra---Shubha yoga-Sh ubha Karana Evam guna
>   visheshana visishtaayaam] Am uka Pravaraamuka Gotromuka Sharmaaham
>   Mama Samasta Pitrunaam Niratishayaananda **Brahma lokaavaaptyaad** i
>   Kanyaa daana kalpokta phalaavaaptaye Anena Varen aasyaam
>   Kanyaamutpaada ishyamaana santatyaa Dwadas haa Varaan Dwadasha
>   paraamscha Purushaan Pavitrika rtum Atmanascha Lakshmi Narayana
>   preetaye Braahma Vivaaha vidhinaa Kanyaa daanmam karishye!
>
> ( After announcing the details of the Desha kaala details on the lines
>   of [----] above, the ‘Kanya Daana Kar ta’ would recite the following :
>   I, of Amuka Prava ra Aamuka Gotra Amuka Sharma, **am performing this K
>   anya Dana so that this auspicious act would faci litate the Phala
>   prapti to let my Pitru Devaas to attain lasting happiness and Brahma
>   loka Nivasa** as also to pave way for the prospective generations out
>   of the union of these Vadhu-Varaas to sanctify me and my wife as also
>   twelve brides and twelve g rooms in future besides pleasing Bhagavan
>   Shri Lak shmi- Narayana !

So, the Phala is not just Brahma Loka prapti but it is the main fruit.

Comment: Thanks. Who is the author of the Smriti Ratna?

Comment: @Ikshvaku No problem ... I do not know who the author is .. the text is probably a dharma-shastra digest like Nirnaya Sindhu, Dharma Sindhu etc

Comment: My dad has Dharma Sindhu with him. Do you know where the Dharma Sindhu talks about kanya dana phala so I can look it up?

Comment: No I don't know .. u can then ask ur dad? I hv read essence of Dharma Sindhu .. I will search in it about this and will update if needed later @Ikshvaku

Comment: Ok thanks. Was just wondering if you knew off the top of your head.

Comment: No I can't remember right now, but as I hv said at the start of the answer, the fruit is Brahma Loka prapti and may be I had read that in Essence of Dharma Sindhu only @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross, nice answer, our panditji was telling us that kanyadan is the best daan and Pitrs pray that someone born in the family will do kanyadan for them.

Comment: Yes Kanyadan has high merits. And thanks that you liked my answer. @Archit

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rickross' answer, I have found other verses that illustrate the punya phala of a kanya dana:

> Viṣṇu (24.34-37).—‘He who gives his girl in marriage by the Brāhma form goes to the regions of Brahman; by the Daiva, to Heaven; by the Ārṣa, to the regions of Viṣṇu; by the Prājāpatya, to the regions of the gods; and by the Gāndharva form, one goes to the region of the Gandharvas.’
>
> Dakṣa (Vīramitrodaya-Saṃskāra, p. 866).—‘The reward accruing from the marrying of a girl by the right form is double in the case of her being given to a Brāhmaṇa; a hundred-thousandfold in that of her being given to a learned Brāhmaṇa; and endless in that of her being given to a thoroughly learned Brāhmaṇa.’

Comment: Is your first reference from the Vishnu purana?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Vishnu *Smriti*